# SharePoint Online masterpage assets are not working through office 365 cdn url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, master-page, public-cdn

I have a SharePoint Online tenant with office 365 cdn enabled. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Tenant settings for CDN]

---

I have a SharePoint site collection with publishing feature and custom scripting enabled. I am trying to refer a CSS file (style.css) which is located in **masterpage** library,
through a content editor webpart.
File is located here- https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/modernComm/_catalogs/masterpage/style.css

*My problem is, CSS file does not load. Here's what I see in the network tab.
CSS file is served from a public cdn which gives is 404 error
https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/*****.sharepoint.com/sites/modernComm/_catalogs/masterpage/style.css*

[image: Masterpage library, content fails to load]

---

I try the same steps by putting the style.css into **Style Library** and strangely this works. See the screenshot. What am I missing about the **MASTERPAGE** library ?

[image: Style Library, content is loads via cdn]